# When does one become considered shomer shaboss?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, grapes-wine, heresy, baal-teshuva

*Clarification* : Mr. X is a orthodox religious Jew. Mr. X has a rebellious phase and violates shaboss. Mr. X later starts keeping the rules again. I'm asking in both cases:

Case 1: Ten people knew about it.

Case 2: Fewer than 10 people knew.

I'm asking specifically in regards to *yayin nesech*. If a person was known to not be shomer shaboss (i.e. not frum) and he (or she) then becomes *shomer shaboss*, when would one be allowed to drink non-mevushal wine with them?

Comment: shachna, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. [Editing in to your question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/17234/edit) a source for your implied claim that _sh'miras Shabas_ is what is determinative of whether someone makes wine _yayin nesech_ would boost your question's quality.

Comment: Also please note that there is a difference between Yayin Nesech and Stam Yeynam.

Comment: Just to point out that this question is only according to those who prohibit uncooked wine touched by non-Sabbath observers.

Comment: After s/he becomes _shomer shaboss_...whenever they want!

Comment: @double aa, "just to point out that this question is only according to those who prohibit uncooked wine touched by non-Sabbath observers." which is a discussion we've had on this site before.

Comment: @SethJ Indeed we have a quite unsatisfactory discussion here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10280/759. I was just pointing it out that the current question only holds under certain opinions.

Comment: Everyone agrees that wine touched by a mechalel Shabbos befarhesya is forbidden ([YD 2:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=25)). The only thing not clear is whether the status "tinok shenishbah" makes it as if it isn't befarhesya, but if it was befarhesya, it's forbidden according to everyone.

Comment: @ba That's in Hilchot Shechita and since we know it doesn't apply in its entirety (ie he doesn't need to convert, his kiddushin is probably kiddushin, he is likely zokek for yibbum etc.) there is great reason to think that the Shulchan Aruch is only referring to his status as a non-Jew vis-a-vis that his Shechita is Neveila. It is not at all clear that he would extend this rule to wine, especially since he doesn't repeat the rule by wine. So no, not everyone agrees.

Comment: @DoubleAA It does apply fully, just that we only use it lechumra. His kidushin therefore IS kidushin, etc., because we can't use this lekula. (Source: Shearim Metzuyanim Bahalachah to Kitzur 72:2) However, we do *fully* use it lechumra.

Comment: @ba So you found a source that holds like you. I never denied such opinions exist, only that _everyone_ holds that. Igrot Moshe OC V 37 for instance holds it's only a minhag.

Comment: @shachna I still have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @DoubleAA I did an edit, hope it clears things up.

Comment: @shachna Sorry, still not sure. When did he touch the wine? During his rebellious phase, or after he started keeping the rules again?

Comment: Once he started keeping the rules again.

Comment: @shachna So you're asking if someone who keeps shabbat would forbid wine just because he has sinned at some point in the past? (PS Using @ followed by my user name alerts me to new messages.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh Deah [124:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=62) says that a yisrael mumar traifs up the wine when he touches it, but he's considered trustworthy when he says he's done teshuvah.

Comment: See the Shach and Gra who limit that ruling to where no one knew he had sinned. If it was known that he sinned, he needs to bring proof that he did teshuva.