# Apostate Jew performing mitzvahs

Tags: halacha, shabbat, avodah-zarah, apostasy

It has been discussed many times on this site that a non-Jew [may not observe Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13448/1713) (in addition to various other mitzvot that are prohibited to non-Jews). We have also seen that a Jew who renounces Judaism, while not losing his official Jewish status, [may have to undergo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7776/1713) some kind of process to reaffirm his commitment to Judaism.

My question is, may a Jew who has renounced Judaism continue to observe Shabbat? Must he? Does it matter if he has converted to some other religion such as Christianity?

Comment: You are referring to the Rama's requiring a dip in the mikva? He says clearly that that is only a rabbinic requirement.

Comment: What about if an apostate Jew poured you wine, is it considered yayin nesech?

Comment: @Aryeh Some say it is forbidden as _stam yeinam_.

Comment: @Aryeh, that question has been asked here somewhere.

Comment: @SethJ, [Yes it is](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10492/1713). Apparently it *is* yayin nesech, which strengthens this question.

Comment: @Aryeh, see above

Comment: @Daniel, we've said elsewhere also that an apostate Jew is a sinning Jew. For purposes of his obligations as a Jew, it means nothing that he doesn't consider himself Jewish.

Comment: @SethJ, so if wine that he touches is considered yayin nesech, how can he do kiddush? That's an important part of Shabbat.

Comment: Beer, scotch, grape juice...what's the question?

Comment: @SethJ beer and scotch don't work erev shabbos, and I was under the impression that grape juice has the same issue of yayin nesech as regular wine does.

Comment: @Daniel, just use Mevushal wine/grape juice.

Answer (score 1):

The halachah is once a Jew, always a Jew. The source most often cited for this is ישראל אף על פי שחטא ישראל הוא (Sanhedrin 44a)--A Jew, even if he has sinned remains a Jew. Rashi in a teshuvah cites this Gemara as the basis for saying that a mumar retains his Jewish status. Thus a Jew cannot lose his obligation to perform mitzvot. The fact that he may lose his status as a Jew *in good standing* and thus is ineligible to write a sefer Torah or perform shechita is irrelevant to his obligation in mitzvot.

Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik explained this by reference to the two types of kedushah that a Jew possesses, symbolized by the two blessings, שלא עשני גוי and אשר בחר בנו מכל העמים. One holiness, that of שלא עשני גוי, is a product of being born a Jew (or converting to Judaism). It cannot be renounced. However, there is a second kedushah which comes from observing the Torah, אשר בחר בנו מכל העמים ונתן לנו את תורתו; regarding this element of kedushah, if a Jew does not observe the mitzvot he loses his status (Chumash Mesoras Harav Vayikra, p. 223):

> One aspect of our chosenness relates to being the progeny of Abraham,
>   and it is for this aspect which we recite the blessing *who has not
>   made me a gentile*. A second chosenness comes through the study of
>   Torah, reflected in the blessing *who has chosen us from among the
>   nations*. This chosenness involves a higher sanctification than is
>   afforded through simple lineage. By understanding the duality of our
>   kedushah, we can explain a puzzling area of Jewish law. The halachic
>   status of a Jew who renounces his religion is complex: although his
>   status as a Jew is compromised, it does not entirely disappear. With
>   regard to specific halachos, an apostate Jew is considered no
>   different from a non-Jew. For example, regarding the slaughter of
>   animals or the writing of Torah scrolls, an apostate is considered to
>   be a non-Jew: his meat would be considered non-kosher, and his Torah
>   scroll would be invalid. On the other hand, if he betroths a woman,
>   his betrothal would be valid. How can we understand the hybrid nature
>   of the halachos concerning an apostate? The apostate Jew retains the
>   sanctity afforded through his lineage—a heritage that cannot be
>   renounced, no matter what he does. This kedushah applies equally to
>   the apostate as it does to the greatest of rabbis. The second
>   kedushah, however, is dependent on the sanctity of the individual
>   attainable only through limud haTorah. The apostate has renounced this
>   second kedushah.