# Wine made/handled by Bnei Noach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, grapes-wine, noahidism

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/wine-made-handled-by-non-religious-jews) question.

---

Is wine made or handled by a Ben Noach, a righteous non-Jew, kosher? There should be no problem with the wine being used for avodah zarah, since the Ben Noach believe in Hashem, and his complete unity (unlike Christians).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is debated by the Gemara ([Avodah Zarah 64b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=64b&format=pdf)). The [Rambam](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5211.htm#4) rules that it is forbidden to drink the wine of a ger toshav, but it is permitted to derive benefit from it. This is the ruling of the Shulchan Aruch as well, regarding all non-idolatrous gentiles ([Yoreh De'ah 124:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%95)).