# The treatment of Jewish unbelievers in Halacha

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, heresy

There is a man, not an *am ha'aretz* by any means nor a *Tinok Shenishba* who has become an Apikores by any definition. He is not evangelical about his unbelief and is observant. He does not publicly violate the Sabbath, but has privately expressed doubt to others regarding belief in God and other fundamentals of Judaism.

How such a man is to be treated in Halacha, e.g., what is the status of wine he touches?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yiddishe Yid and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Please elaborate on how do you know that he's an Apikores - did he say that, or he said something that sounds like Apikorsut?

Comment: Just to clarify what's being asked: the man in question theoretically davens with the congregation 3 times a day, studies the Torah and does not publicly violate the Sabbath, but has privately expressed doubt regarding the existence of G-d, the divine origin of the Torah, or similar matters?

Comment: Josh k - Yes as far as I know

Comment: Al Berko - The former.

Comment: If you are interested in a Modern Orthodox perspective on this matter, YC Torah has a 5 part source review series exploring different facets thereof: https://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/the-status-of-a-non-believer-regarding-wine-and-other-matters-part-1-status-of-a-shabbos-violator-in-rishonim-and-poskim/

Comment: Josh K - I can't find the other five parts. The first part was very good can you please send the other links.

Comment: @Yiddishe, glad you find it useful.  it's hard to copy-paste 5 links. If you go to the top of the article you can click bak to the Yoreh Deah section and find the resr of them. Here's part 4: https://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/the-status-of-a-non-believer-regarding-wine-and-other-matters-part-4-status-of-one-who-does-not-believe-understanding-rambam/

Comment: @YiddisheYid when someone asks for clarification to your question, it is highly recommended to [edit] your clarifications directly into the question. I allowed myself to do so but you can further [edit] as required. Thanks

Comment: relevant: [Wine made/handled by non-religious Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10280/11501)